# Jacoco report 0 classes

Tags: java, maven, docker, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am new with mvn & jacoco and I have an issue with `mvn jacoco:report` who found 0 classes in the  jacoco.exec file

The jacoco agent is executed inside a docker container : `-javaagent:/opt/jboss/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent.jar=destfile=/opt/jboss/jacoco/jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6667`

I passed the option in standalone.conf

```
#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jboss/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent.jar=destfile=/opt/jboss/jacoco/jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6667"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

is it enough?

When I launched `jacoco:dump` I successfully connect to my container and a jacoco.exec file is created locally (not empty)

My app is like that :

- Docker container : wildfly (where I need code coverage)
- Local machine : My maven application
- Local machine : My selenium maven project (where I execute jacoco)

My plugin config pom :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
            <dataFile>/home/mypath/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            <reset>true</reset>
            <address>172.17.0.3</address>
            <port>6667</port>
            <append>false</append>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Edit : The jacococli generate a report so my exec file is correct

Edit : Ok so I think I find my issue the problem is my maven app is a dependency of my selenium project, it seems that jacoco-maven-plugin is unable to use a dependency (to get all the class files) to create the report but with ant there is more options so here is my solution :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="report">
                                <!-- Execute an ant task within maven -->
                                <echo message="Generating JaCoCo Reports" />
                                <taskdef name="report"
                                    classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask">
                                    <classpath
                                        path="xxxtarget/*.jar" />
                                </taskdef>
                                <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report" />
                                <report>
                                    <executiondata>
                                        <fileset dir="${basedir}/target">
                                            <include name="jacoco.exec" />
                                        </fileset>
                                    </executiondata>
                                    <structure name="Integration Tests Coverage Report">
                                        <classfiles>
                                            <fileset dir="xxx/target" >
                                                <include name="*.jar"/>
                                            </fileset>
                                        </classfiles>                                   
                                    </structure>
                                    <html destdir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/html" />
                                </report>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I finally have the report automatically generated by the pom

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing the jacoco report goal?

You can try running the command something like this:

```
mvn -B -DskipTests org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:report -Djacoco.dataFile="<..>\target\jacoco-merged.exec"
```

Comment: I added my pom plugin config, I just run mvn jacoco:report I tried your command but it returns the same "Analyzed bundle 'selenium' with 0 classes" / but with this command : java -jar jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles myapp.jar --html html I have a full report !! so my exec file is correct but I don't want to create the report using the cli

Comment: I think there can be 2 issues:
1. It's not looking for correct .exec file.Please check maven log once to see if its 
    picking the correct file path.
2. Check if you are running the command at correct project level.

Comment: 1. the path is correct 2. I am not sure to understand but that let me think about something else and I find this issue : https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/553 "generation of report requires class files and report goal uses classes of module where it is executed and hence generates report containing them, so the behavior that you observe is a correct one, because module webapp-integration-tests has no classes. To have a report that includes classes of other modules within Maven reactor please use report-aggregate" I'll try it next Monday when I'll on it again and let you know